# Spring Cloud LoadBalancerClient - Hoxton SR8 - throwing error

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Previously were using Spring cloud Finchley.M9 release. We used LoadBalancerClient as like below.

```
'''import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UriResolver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UriResolver.class);

    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;

    @Autowired
    public UriResolver(LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient) {
        this.loadBalancerClient = loadBalancerClient;
    }

    public URI getBaseUri(String vendorName) {
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancerClient.choose(vendorName);
        URI uri = null;
        if (!Objects.isNull(instance)) {
            uri = instance.getUri();
            LOGGER.debug("LoadBalancer Instance specific URI: " + instance.getUri());
            LOGGER.debug("LoadBalancer Instance specific ServiceId: " + instance.getServiceId());
            LOGGER.debug("LoadBalancer Instance specific Host: " + instance.getHost());
        }
        return uri;
    }

}'''
```

Now we have upgraded the spring cloud version to Hoxton.SR8. We get the below error while starting the spring boot app.

Bean method 'loadBalancerClient' in 'RibbonAutoConfiguration' not loaded because AllNestedConditions 2 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on RibbonAutoConfiguration.RibbonClassesConditions.RibbonPresent @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.netflix.ribbon.Ribbon'; NestedCondition on RibbonAutoConfiguration.RibbonClassesConditions.AsyncRestTemplatePresent @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate'; NestedCondition on RibbonAutoConfiguration.RibbonClassesConditions.RestTemplatePresent @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate'; NestedCondition on RibbonAutoConfiguration.RibbonClassesConditions.IClientPresent @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.netflix.client.IClient'

Comment: Did you add the ribbon starter?

Comment: I dont have ribbon starter. When i used Finchley.M9 also i didnt have ribbon starter. While i upgrade to Hoxton.SR8, is it mandatory to add ribbon starter?

Comment: It worked after adding spring-cloud-starter-ribbon. Thanks spencergibb